# ASP.NET Changes to externally linked config file cause IIS application to restart?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have a config file linked from web.config e.g.

```
<features configSource="feature.config" />
```

When I make changes to the "feature.config" file the IIS application appears to restart, is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behaviour by default as typically any changes made to the web.config will cause an application restart however this can be overridden for app.config files. From the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8x4ket8%28VS.80%29.aspx):

> Saving a Web.config file restarts the
>   application. You can alternatively use
>   the configSource attribute of
>   individual section elements to point
>   to a secondary configuration file that
>   does not cause an application restart
>   when it is changed.

Although you have moved some of your configurations into a linked config file they are still effectively part of your web.config file and any changes made there will have the same effect as if you made the change directly in the web.config file itself. However you can specify a section to not restart the application on change by using the restartOnExternalChanges attribute in the section definition. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228167%28VS.80%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228245%28VS.80%29.aspx) for further details. However, according to the documentation this is not valid for ASP.NET applications which makes the above statement a little misleading.

Comment: sorry, just to clarify. Making Changes to the externally reference feature.config file will restart the application?

Comment: @Mark 909 - my original answer described the default behaviour but it does appear there is a way round this buried in the msdn.